# Number 350 in Parashat Noach

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-noach

It says in Parashat Noach that the ark should be 300 Amot long and 50 Amot width. And it says that Noach lived 300 years and 50 years after the flood.

What is the connection between them ?
Anything in Chazal or the Mefarshim ?

Comment: But the teivah was also 30 amos high - so really its 380?

Comment: A starting question of why was the ark was that specific size may be a better place to start.

Comment: The Ben L' Ashri writes that 50 represents the gates of wisdom. He also writes that 300 is the gematria of something with Yud, but I forgot what he said.

Answer (score 4):

Wonderful question! The Torah is known for its precision, and indeed, there appears to be a fascinating connection worth exploring.

The Medrash Lekach Tov says these two facts are intrinsically connected:

> **ויחי נח אחר המבול שלש מאות שנה וחמשים שנה.** אומר אני כנגד אורך התבה
> ורחבה. דכתיב שלש מאות אמה אורך התבה חמשים אמה רחבה (בראשית ו טו).

However, while this Medrash offers insight, it doesn't explain why these numbers are connected. In the Sefer [Torah Shleimah](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51452&st=&pgnum=231), a compilation of midrashim, there is an attempt to provide several explanations.

The first explanation, based on a Drush from a Talmid of the Rashba, suggests that the number 300 corresponds to the first letter of Hashem's name, "שד-י," while the number 50 corresponds to the letter "נ" of Hashem's name, "א-ד-נ-י." These divine powers protected Noach.

Another perspective presented in the Sefer Torah Shlomeh is related to the long life of Noah. He lived for 950 years, in contrast to his son Shem, who lived for only 600 years. These extra 350 was a zchus for building the Ark.

He also mentions that there are many Kabbalah reasons for the similarity between these numbers.